# Cypress Angular : CypressError “Timed out retrying: Expected to find content”

Tags: angular, cypress

I run this following test in cypress, i have this error message on the last step (click): 
Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: .button-darkblue, but never found it.

This is my code :

```
describe('Test Login', () => {
it('Test login with good info', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/login/')
    cy.url().should('eq', 'http://localhost:4200/login')
    cy.get('.login-box').should('be.visible')
    cy.fixture('adminData').then((adminData) => {
        cy.get('#loginForm').within(function () {
            cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .blue > input').clear().type(adminData.email)
            cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .blue > input').clear().type(adminData.password)
            cy.get('.button-darkblue').click()
        })
    })
})
```

})

This is my html

```
<div class="frow justify-between login-action-buttons" id="loginActionButtons">
<div class="grid-example-square">
    <button (click)="register()" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" class="button-text-blue">
        Create an account
    </button>
</div>
<div class="">
    <button class="button-darkblue">
        Connect
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I Solve it by get out the line of code from within(function)

```
describe('Test Login', () => {
it('Test login with good info', () => {
cy.visit('http://localhost:4200/login/')
cy.url().should('eq', 'http://localhost:4200/login')
cy.get('.login-box').should('be.visible')
cy.fixture('adminData').then((adminData) => {
    cy.get('#loginForm').within(function () {
        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .blue > input').clear().type(adminData.email)
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .blue input').clear().type(adminData.password)
    })
cy.get('.button-darkblue').click()
})
```

})